# Duplicated Unanswered Questions page, with missing features on one

Tags: bug, filtering, unanswered-questions

On the homepage, upon scrolling right to the bottom, you get presented these links:
[image: Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions, or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions]

Clicking on "complete list of questions" takes you to the [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page. Weirdly though, clicking on "unanswered questions" takes you to the [/unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) page, which I would not expect, given the existence of [/questions?tab=Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered).

This alternative "/unanswered" page is also lacking in some features: the filter button is entirely missing. Instead, it has [image: some tabs]

which replaces some but not all of the functionality of the filter button.

Additionally, it has an almost identical user interface, which led me to think I was the subject of a cruel A/B test until I noticed the URL.

Comment: Well they are different, one is no answers at all, the other is no positively scoring or accepted answers

Comment: Still, it's confusing having multiple, and the behaviour can be almost replicated with &filters=NoAnswers. Perhaps the best resolution would be to add a filter for questions with no upvoted/accepted answers?